# P/Invoke AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pinvoke, libvlc

I have an unmanaged function call that is throwing this exception when I try to pass it the path to a file name.

I've read that this is likely caused by the DLL itself but I don't think that is the case since the DLL is used in another application, so the problem is likely in my method calling the function.

The specification:

```
libvlc_media_new_path (libvlc_instance_t *p_instance, const char *path)
```

Description:

```
p_instance  the instance
path    local filesystem path
```

And my method:

```
[DllImport("libvlc", EntryPoint = "libvlc_media_new_path")]
public static extern IntPtr NewMedia(IntPtr instance,
                            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string path);
```

I think I'm missing the convention call but what would that likely be? Or would it be something else causing this exception?

EDIT: Based on some comments I did some poking around and found... well, nothing. The struct for the instance is opaque, which means I have no idea in Laymans terms. My guess is that it means you don't need to reconstruct it in the application that is using it?

In a blind guess based on [this](https://www.powerbasic.com/support/pbforums/showthread.php?t=51978), I replaced the return value that I had been using with the function responsible for setting the *p_instance value to a `long` instead of an `IntPtr` since when it was an `IntPtr` it was returning 0, and with a long I was seeing a value. Again, what an `IntPtr` is I don't really know. I was pretty happy to see something not 0 in the instance variable but when I ran it past that, it errored out again.

EDIT: I've expanded the question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213863/writing-a-lite-weight-libvlc-wrapper-need-help-newish-to-p-invoke).

Comment: You can try `[DllImport("libvlc", EntryPoint = "libvlc_media_new_path"), CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl]`, but that might not be the cause. Are you sure that the `instance` pointer you're passing to it is correct? Also, check the character encoding. Is the DLL function expecting ANSI or Unicode strings?

Comment: Given that the DLL was written in this century, I'm going to hazard a guess that it's expecting Unicode. I'm pretty certain that the instance pointer is correct but I'll check on it.

Comment: It's very likely you are on to something with the Instance issue. I currently having it returning an IntPtr which is 0 after the call that initializes it, even though no exception is being called. The documentation says it returns a struct. Now I just need to find the documentation about the Struct Layout.

Comment: It really is the same problem as your previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception you're seeing and the declaration you've provided for the native function,

```
libvlc_media_new_path (libvlc_instance_t *p_instance, const char *path)
```

your p/invoke declaration is incorrect. You've mismatched the calling conventions. The default for the .NET p/invoke system is stdcall (to match the Windows API functions), but the default for C and C++ code is cdecl. You have to tell .NET explicitly that your function uses the cdecl calling convention.

So change it to look like this:

```
[DllImport("libvlc", EntryPoint = "libvlc_media_new_path", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr NewMedia(IntPtr instance,
                                     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string path);
```

Of course, I'm guessing that you're right about the return value being a pointer. The native function declaration you've shown is missing the return type.

As for your question about the `instance` parameter, and whether you are correctly using the `IntPtr` type: The parameter is a pointer to a `libvlc_instance_t`, so you have two basic ways of making that work using p/invoke. First is to declare the parameter as an `IntPtr`, which gets it marshalled like a raw pointer value. This is not particularly useful for cases where the pointer needs to be anything other than opaque (i.e. retrieved from one native function, stored, and then passed to another native function). Second is to declare a managed structure that mirrors the native structure, and then write the p/invoke declaration to use this structure so that the marshaller will handle things automatically. This is most useful if you actually need to interact with the values stored in the structure pointed to by the pointer.

In this case, after a Google search, it looks like you're using one of the VLC APIs. Specifically [this one](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga051342375370f3bf3821a537d4413435). That [also tells us](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__core.html#ga316d739a80da4678206c79f4d6c2e284) what an `libvlc_instance_t` is: it is an opaque structure that represents a libvlc instance. So declaring a managed structure is not an option here, because the structure is treated as opaque even by the native code. All you really need is the pointer, passed back and forth; a perfect case for the first method I talked about above. So the declaration shown above is your winner.

The only battle now is obtaining a valid pointer to a libvlc instance that you can pass to the function whenever you call it. Chances are good that will come from a prior call to a function like [`libvlc_new`](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__core.html#ga915aa5778053d7b52ff9f6ba6e2f7764), which is documented as creating and intializing a new libvlc instance. Its return value is exactly what you need here. So unless you've already created a libvlc instance (in which case, use that pointer), you will also need to call this function and store its result.

If [the documentation](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__core.html#ga915aa5778053d7b52ff9f6ba6e2f7764) is correct about the required values for the `libvlc_new` function's parameters, you can declare it very simply:

```
[DllImport("libvlc", EntryPoint = "libvlc_new", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr NewCore(int argc, IntPtr argv);
```

And call it thus:

```
IntPtr pLibVlc = NewCore(0, IntPtr.Zero);
// now pLibVlc should be non-zero
```

And of course, I know nothing about the VLC APIs, but my general knowledge of API design tells me that you will probably need to call the [`libvlc_release`](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__core.html#ga9ed5af1680546a68242f34b54eeb27b2) function with that same pointer to an instance once you're finished with it.

Comment: You nailed what I'm doing on the head. Is the IntPtr value always going to be 0 when I hover over it while debugging though?

Comment: @Will No. It is a pointer to something. If you're not experienced with native code, you can think of it like an address to something stored in memory. It "points" to an object stored in memory. So it won't be 0 unless it is invalid and there is no object, it'll be some random long number. The linked documentation indicates that the function returns 0 (NULL) when the function fails. It is failing because you're not passing it a valid pointer to an instance of libvlc.

Comment: Alright then it's failing. This is what I have for that function:
        [DllImport("libvlc", EntryPoint = "libvlc_new", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr NewCore(int argc, 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String[] argv);

Before it was unbalanced, now it's not returning anything unbalanced. So the problem comes back to this function.

Comment: @Will You can vastly simplify the declaration of the `libvlc_new` function if the documentation is correct about the required values for the parameters. I'll update my answer with the correct declaration.

Comment: Alright thanks. Is there a way to message someone privately so that the conversation isn't taking place via comments?

Comment: @Will No, the site isn't really designed for that. Generally, if you have a follow-up question, you ask a new question. But asking a clarification question or two in the comments is A-OK.

Comment: Alrighty good to know, thanks. Okay so I did that change you suggested, No Good. IntPtr value is still 0, still getting memory access violation error.

Comment: @Will No idea what's wrong then. Everything I see looks right. So either I'm missing something, or there's something going wrong in code that I can't see. Like I said, I'm not an expert on using the VLC APIs. Can you use the VLC APIs from a C++ application? It's probably time to post a new question. Make sure you document all the things you've done so far, and explain clearly what isn't working.

Comment: New Question @ [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213863/writing-a-lite-weight-libvlc-wrapper-need-help-newish-to-p-invoke)

Answer (score 0):

Try without the [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)], usually works for me.